# sha1 hash for std::vector<uint8_t> using crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++

I have collection of vectors of the type `std::vector<uint8_t>` and I need to store a hashed value for each individual vector. 
I would like to use crypto++ for this. But I am not sure if it is possible. From what I can tell, I would be able if I made it a `std::vector<byte>`. However, the examples I have seen also provides the hash value in a `std::vector<byte>`. So is what I want to do at all possible with crypto++ or do I need to look for another library? If yes, can you provided an example?

*EDIT:* 
Example with byte pointer (https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/User_guide:_cryptlib.h):

```
byte const* pbData1 = ...;
byte const* pbData2 = ...
unsigned int nData1Len = ...;
unsigned int nData2Len = ...;
byte abDigest[SHA::DIGESTSIZE];

SHA hash;
hash.Update(pbData1, nData1Len);
hash.Update(pbData2, nData2Len);
hash.Final(abDigest);

// abDigest now contains the hash of pbData1 and pbData2;
// the object 'hash' can now be reused to calculate another digest

...

SHA hash;
hash.Update(pbData1, nData1Len);
hash.Update(pbData2, nData2Len);
if (!hash.Verify(abDigest))
    throw "abDigest does not contain the right hash";
```

Comment: What is `byte`? `std::byte`? Also, for those of us how are not falimilar with crypto++ it would help if you showed us how the hash for `std::vector<byte>` is computed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have update with an example, yes `std:byte` you can get the byte pointer from the vector pretty easy :)

Comment: According to the example, you should be able to calculate the hash for each of your vectors as follows: `SHA hash; hash.Update(v.data(), v.size()); hash.Final(abDigest);`, where `v` is a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: By the way, I don't think at all that `byte` is `std::byte`. According to `config.h` of crypto++ library, `byte` is it an alias for `unsigned char`, which is a very different type than `std::byte`.

Comment: oh thanks for caching that @DanielLangr

Comment: @Lars - The Crypto++ examples on the wiki suck for hashing and MAC's. I need to get some examples together for hashing. Related to `std::vector`, and if you use [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipeline), a `VectorSink` will be available in Crypto++ 7.1. Also see [Commit ac43bee69850](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/ac43bee69850).

Comment: @Daniel and Lars - You guys are right. The `byte` is `CryptoPP::byte`. Also see [`std::byte`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/std::byte) on the Crypto++ wiki.